# Incremental copy from linux to windows share

Tags: windows, linux, backup, networking

Using a cronjob I'm daily backing up a linux system (ubuntu) onto a windows network share so it gets picked up by our organisation's backup system.

Currently I'm copying using `cp -au`. Although this works ok to preserve as much filesystem information as possible I am thinking of compressing the files first to a tar or  tar.gz archive before copying over. However I want to minimize the time it takes to copy the archive to the windows share - I only have a 60 minute time-window.

What is the best solution to copy only the minimal amount of data in this situation? As a subquestion would compressing the archive make it much harder to copy only changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the best solution to copy only
>   the minimal amount of data in this
>   situation?

You can use [`rsync`](http://www.samba.org/rsync/) instead of `cp`.

`rsync` will only copy what has changed.
Even when only a part of a file changes, rsync is smart enough to figure it out.

Its syntax similar to that of scp and it can preserve all meta information.

With `rsync -z`, data can also be compressed.

> -z, --compress
>       With this option, rsync compresses the file data as it is sent to the
>   destination machine, which reduces the
>   amount of data being transmitted --
>   something that is useful over a slow
>   connection.
>
> Note that this option typically achieves better compression ratios
>   than can be achieved by using a
>   compressing remote shell or a
>   compressing transport because it takes
>   advantage of the implicit information
>   in the matching data blocks that are
>   not explicitly sent over the
>   connection.

Comment: You need to setup an rsync server for it, right?

Comment: I found Deltacopy (http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DeltaCopy.jsp) which can be used on windows together with rsync on linux and seems pretty easy to setup.

Comment: Not necessarily, rsync can copy on a windows share like cp. It is almost a drop-in replacement for cp. You will have to look carefully at the options though.

Comment: When I change a few files in the tgz archive will that make more differences for rsync throughout the archive than if I would change the same in only a tar archive (not compressed)?